# symfony custom form type with assets

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I've created a custom form type in symfony2. This formtype has it's own template and this is working fine.

The form type also needs some javascript on the clientside to work nicely.
I would like to add this javascript to the page using the same template I use to render the widget. It's a bit more of a hassle to do this manually.
I could add the javascript manually on each page, but it would be nice if that just happened automatically.

I can't add the javascript just before or after the element itself, as it has a dependency to jquery which is only loaded at the bottom of the body.

I tried using a block which is defined in the "main template" (it is named `block_javascript`) to add the custom javascripts to the footer of the page, but it seems the rendering of forms works a little different and the block is not available.

I'm using assetic to prepare and return assets.

Is there a way I can use blocks from the main template being rendered when rendering a form widget?

Comment: I really really don't think so, but take a look at this bundle https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle, it gives you an additional `form_javascripts` function which you can use to render the js for your forms.

Comment: The function is intereseting, but I think it won't work in combination with assetic which I'm using (but did not mention in question, question is updated now). I'm getting a feeling to get this working in a nice way would require a lot of additional code. Adding the js+css manually on the page appears a lot simpler and leaves more room for exceptions where you need something slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think yet about all the consequences or if it's doable, but here an idea that can solve your problem: use the event dispatcher.

- an event for assets addition
- a service that hold a list of assets to use and subscribe to above event
- a Twig extension that use above service to make assets accessible in the template
- trigger the event in the `buildView()` function of your form type with right parameters
- use the Twig extension in your layout template

It theorically should work.

Comment: This could indeed work, not just in theory, but also in reality. Although I don't really like to store information like this in a service, sure I could narrow the scope of the service but it is still messy. It also does not work nicely with assetic (or I'm missing something). I forgot to mention assetic in original question, it is updated now.

Comment: I should work with Assetic if the service register a named AssetReference (e.g. "dynamic_assets") to an AssetCollection. Then you should refer to that  in your template with `'@dynamic_assets'`

Comment: Having played with it for a while I elected not to use this solution, but use a manual approach. If a form needs javascript, you need to make sure it is included in the page manually via either a site-wide javascript or single-page javascript. This because of flexibility and to prevent problems with automatically added javascripts. There is always that one exception. If however you really want to add javascript automatically, this seems the way to go. Even though you still leave data in your service.